# Why the timer never stop after starting?

Tags: c#, winforms

user control :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Extract
{
    public partial class LoadingLabel : Label
    {
        private int Interval = 1000;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer;
        private int counter = 0;

        public bool IsOpen { get; set; }
        public LoadingLabel()
        {
            this.Font = new Font("Arial", 14, FontStyle.Bold);

            StartCountDownTimer(Interval, IsOpen);
        }

        public void StartCountDownTimer(int Interval, bool EnableTimer)
        {
            _timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
            {
                Interval = Interval,
                Enabled = false
            };

            _timer.Enabled = EnableTimer;

            _timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                base.Text += ".";

                counter++;

                if (counter == 4)
                {
                    base.Text = "";
                    counter = 0;
                }
            };
        }

        [DefaultValue("")]
        public override string Text
        {
            get => base.Text;
            set
            {
                base.Text = !DesignMode ? "" : value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then after dragging the control into form1 designer from the toolbox this line in the constructor make the control timer to stop when running the application :

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            loadingLabel1.StartCountDownTimer(1000, false);
         }
```

In this button click event I start the timer again :

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadingLabel1.IsOpen = true;
            loadingLabel1.StartCountDownTimer(1000, true);
         }
```

And then here I want to stop it again :

```
private async Task DownloadAsync()
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Downloading";
            loadingLabel1.StartCountDownTimer(1000, false);
        }
```

but it's never stop in the async Task DownloadAsync. Why it's not stopping ?

I also tried to set isOpen to false :

```
private async Task DownloadAsync()
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Downloading";
            loadingLabel1.IsOpen = false;
            loadingLabel1.StartCountDownTimer(1000, false);
        }
```

but it didn't stop either.

Comment: You're creating a new timer every time you call `StartCountDownTimer`. What you need to do is check if `_timer` is assigned before creating a new instance... So something like: `if (_timer == null)` ... then create a new instance, otherwise work with the current instance.